# Laravel sum on ->first() sums more than 1 result

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following eloquent query

```
$raw = Model::select('out', 'in')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();
```

That returns a collection of a single item, where Out = 0.0 and In = 90.0.

If I then do this:

```
$sumO = $raw->sum('out');
$sumI = $raw->sum('in');
```

I get `$sumO = 13,651.41` and `$sumI = 13371.69`

I don't understand, because those sums don't even equal the sum of my entire table for those colums.

But it seems like`->sum()` is being called on the entire table/query instead of just the `first` result like I thought it would.

Now, I know sum of a single row is weird, and I'm not actually doing this in production. I just want to know what it is doing.

Shouldn't it still just sum the 1 number to equal itself?

Comment: The `first()` returns the a model and not a collection. Then you are calling the `sum` on the model and that is performing a query to the database.

Answer (score 0):

It's just one row when using ->first(), so there's no need to use ->sum() just use $raw->in and $raw->out.

Also, ->sum() used with a single column at a time.